# ArcMap 10.7 Pictometry Add-In Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows, pictometry

I recently realized that when closing out of ArcMap, the process itself remains running in the background until my computer is either restarted or I manually kill each ArcMap process individually. I could not figure out what the issue was. I did some digging and read that it could be an issue with my ArcMap template (Normal.mxt) or with an add-in that was running and holding onto some reference files.

So, I tried both options and deleted my Normal.mxt as well as any ESRI Add-Ins that I had installed. In my case the only ESRI Add-In I had installed was the Pictometry toolbar.

My issue was resolved but I am trying to determine if this is something anyone else has experience with the Pictometry add-in or was my issue was simply resolved by deleting my Normal.mxt file?